# md-button in ASP.NET form is not correctly sized

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, angular-material

I have a ASP.NET form in which I'd like to add a md-button but when I put my md-button inside the form it gets resized and it doesn't fit the row as I want it.

I can't find any documentation on this behaviour, I tried to set the layout on the button itself, put it in a md-input-container, etc...

I want this button in the form so I don't have to rewrite the submit form function myself.

Here's my form in HTML :

```
<div layout-padding layout="column">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <md-input-container class="mt-35" layout="row">
            <label>Ton email :</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container layout="row">
            <label>Ton mot de passe :</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container layout="row">
            <md-checkbox aria-label="Rester connecté">
                Rester connecté
            </md-checkbox>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Me connecter</md-button>
        <!-- This button doesn't fit -->
    }
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Connect with Facebook</md-button>
    <!-- This one does -->
</div>
```

I didn't change any CSS for these, i'm working with Angular Material 1.1.0

Here's two screenshots of what I'd like to achieve and what I have now :

[image: What I have now]
That's what I have now, with the code I wrote above.

[image: What I want]
That's what I want to achieve.

EDIT : 
Here's my additional CSS :

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.mt-35 {
    margin-top: 35px !important;
}

.mb-35 {
    margin-bottom: 35px !important;
}
.mb-15 {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
}
.md-content.md-default-theme, md-content {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.md-datepicker-input-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
.md-datepicker-input {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your CSS

Comment: I'm just using angular material 1.1.0 from https://github.com/angular/material
The only additional CSS I wrote has nothing to do with this I think but I'll post it

Comment: Use the inspector on your browser developer tools and you'll see whatever CSS is stopping it from going the full length.

Comment: Already did that, on the button and on all child element I have `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: If i just remove the form tag, the button renders correctly on my page.

Comment: That's why I said to use the inspector.  Your button may be fine, but you have to check all the elements your button is contained within.  One of them is limiting it.  You can probably give that form a custom width.

Comment: Thanks @Jhorra , but I found the issue myself, I've posted the answer bellow. The problem was with the layout system of angular material, when declaring a form with Razor, it doesn't get any layout attribute so it messes up with the other layout options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

The form was messing with the layouts, I have it working by adding the layout attribute in the BeginForm method :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @layout = "column" }))
            {
                <md-input-container class="mt-35" layout="row">
                    <label>Ton email :</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container layout="row">
                    <label>Ton mot de passe :</label>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container layout="row">
                    <md-checkbox aria-label="Rester connecté">
                        Rester connecté
                    </md-checkbox>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-button-no-margin" layout-padding type="submit">Me connecter</md-button>
            }
```

And custom CSS to get rid of the margin in `md-button` class :

```
.md-button-no-margin {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```